# Transfering my Ubuntu install onto a replacement hard drive

Tags: partitioning, hard-drive, backup

Today I am planning on swapping out my ridiculously small 20gb hard drive, for a less small 80gb. Only issue is that it's my Ubuntu drive and I'd rather not go through the install process again. I really have 2 separate questions here.

1. I know that 14.10 is coming fairly soon, so I could just wait to re-install Ubuntu onto it then. If so, will a backup from 14.04 carry my installed applications and files into a 14.10 install? I've never really looked into what the backup function covers.
2. If option 1 doesn't work and I do have to find a way to clone the drive, how would I go about doing this? I'm out of IDE slots on my computer so I have no way of having both hard drives attached simultaneously to copy it using Clonezilla.

If all else fails I can just go through the process again on the new drive.

Answer (score 0):

For question 2, I assume you have at least 2 IDE ports ... else there is no way to do your copy

I'd put in the two drives then boot off a live CD/USB disk.

The safest/clearest way to then copy the partition would be using gparted.

Answer (score 0):

In response to #2:

First you should back up all your important files to a separate disk.  Then, if you don't have an extra IDE port, see if you have an available SATA port. If you have a usable SATA port, I suggest you try to clone your 20GB IDE hard drive to a larger SATA hard drive.  Upon a successful clone, you should be able to boot Ubuntu 14.04 on your SATA drive and still have all your installed applications.  When Ubuntu 14.10 is available, you can use the Software Updater to upgrade from Ubuntu 14.04 to Ubuntu 14.10.

Comment: A backup is unnecessary. The question already is about copying/cloning the current disk content, which is (almost) exactly what a backup does.

Comment: I suggested a backup of any important files just in case the clone operation goes bad.

Comment: While in general backups are a good idea, think about how a backup is made: data is copied from a source to a destination. Now think about how a partition clone is made: data is copied from source to destination. The two are basically the same and partition cloning is indeed a common form of data backup. What you're suggesting is to create a backup B in case the subsequent backup A somehow damages the original data. What would you suggest against the risk that B goes wrong? Another backup C just to be on the safe side?

Comment: Making a backup before cloning sounds like unnecessary repetition to someone who already knows how to clone a hard drive. For anyone who is cloning a hard drive for the first time, be careful to choose the target and source correctly.